# ZedGraph adjust Y axis to show whole curve

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am new to ZedGraph, however I managed to create simple chart and enabled scrolling along the x axis. My problem is that I cant figure how to force the Y axis to autoadjust to show the whole section of the curve. Graphically depicted I want instead of this

```
          _______________________
          |                     |
          | \            _______|
          |  \          /       |
          |___\________/________|
               \______/
```

to adjust the Y axis (or to pan the chart) to look like this

```
          _______________________
          | \            _______|
          |  \          /       |
          |   \        /        |
          |____\______/_________|
```

where the inside of the rectangle is what is visible.

I thought that

```
myPane.YAxis.Scale.MinAuto = true;
myPane.YAxis.Scale.MaxAuto = true;
myPane.IsBoundedRanges = true;
```

should force the axis to behave like I described, but appratenly not.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/P_ZedGraph_GraphPane_IsBoundedRanges.htm), you'll want to set

```
myPane.IsBoundedRanges = false;
```

...which tells ZedGraph to use all Y values to set the Y-axis scale, rather than just the Y values for points whose X values are currently scrolled to be visible.

Comment: Actually I want the Y axis to adjust for the points whose X are currently visible. Lets say that I have points (1,9)(2,8)(3,7)(4,6)(5,5) and on the X axis there are currently points 1,2,3 visible, so I want to have points 9,8,7 on the Y axis and nothing more. When I scroll to 2,3,4 on x axis, I want the y axis to shift to 8,7,6 and so on.